# Why does my Rspec tests send real mails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, actionmailer

I taught that, with an option like `delivery_method = :test` in my `config/environments/test.rb` I should not receive any mails while running my Rspec tests:

**config/environments/test.rb:**

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

But in my tests, when I create a user with FactoryGirl and the user has an `after_save` callback that sends a signup-notification, this email will be sent:

**myspec.rb:**

```rb
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :login => 'johndoe')
```

**user_observer.rb:**

```rb
class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_create(user)
    UserMailer.signup_notification(user).deliver
  end
end
```

**action_mailer.rb:**

```rb
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "...",
  :port => "25",
  :domain => "...",
  :user_name => "...",
  :password => "...",
  :authentication => :plain
}
```

What can be wrong?

I'm using:

- Rails 3.2.2
- buildin ActionMailer
- RSpec-Rails
- FactoryGirl
- Guard

Comment: Could it be that, this `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp` masks my configuration in `environment/test.rb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp masks your configuration in environment/test.rb

I propose you next solution: create fixture with specific data for each scope.
like in [enter link description here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file)
in my case it looks like:

**my config.yml**

```
 development:
      support_mail: test@test.test
      smtp_user_name: test@test.test
      smtp_password: test
      smtp_domain: test.test
      smtp_address: test.test.test
      smtp_port: => 999

    test:
      support_mail: test@test.test
      smtp_user_name: test@test.test
      smtp_password: test
      smtp_domain: test.test
      smtp_address: test.test.test
      smtp_port: => 999

    production:
      support_mail: somth@somth.com
      smtp_user_name: somth@somth.com
      smtp_password: somth
      smtp_domain: somth.com
      smtp_address: smtp.somth.com
      smtp_port: => 587
```

**my environment.rb**

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
#initialize custom config variables
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/config.yml")[Rails.env]
    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      :user_name => APP_CONFIG["smtp_user_name"], #ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
      :password => APP_CONFIG["smtp_password"], #  ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
      :domain => APP_CONFIG["smtp_domain"],
      :address => APP_CONFIG["smtp_address"],
      :port => APP_CONFIG["smtp_port"],
      :authentication => :plain,
      :enable_starttls_auto => false
    }
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Comment: So the `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method ` was the offender. I already use scope specific configuration (via SettingsLogic).